# Should style.scss interact with style.css using @import or --watch or anything else?

Tags: html, sass, web

I notice it does @import with some mixins and partials, but I cannot seem to understand why the programmers did not write in @import style.css. They instead import Susy, bourbon, vendors, utilities, and bases. I don't get it.

I tried writing in some code to get my website to print out paper correctly by getting rid of the navigation bar that kept on randomly appearing on the page.

```
@media print {
    .storefront-primary-navigation 
    {display; none !important;}
}
```

I consulted with other programmers, and they told me that that is the correct class for the navigation bar (not ID #nav). Also, they told me it might be a compilation issue. So, I started to look at .scss and started to ask this.

It's a website for one of my clients. You could inspect the elements. coastalmicrogreens.com

I would also like to add that I am not the most experienced. I work with this under another watchful eye to ensure I do not make any mistakes that could affect security, even though this site is under great security measures.

Answer (score 0):

There's a semicolon in your code that should be a colon. Instead of `display; none !important;` it should read `display: none !important;`.

SCSS does not import CSS, because it *generates* (compiles) CSS. Websites cannot use SCSS directly for styling; that's why it has to get compiled into CSS first.